# Dictionary<HashSet<uint>,string> GroupBy after Intersection

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary `Dictionary<HashSet<uint>, string>` and it is populated as well. Every key is a `HashSet<uint>` so there may be multiple entries in it. Now I want to group by my Dictionary and store into another dictionary which is `Dictionary<HashSet<uint>,List<string>>`. Group by operation is considered to be performed as follows:

1st key value pair:

```
========================
| Key       |  Value   |
========================
|  71       |  Foot    |
|  72       |          |
|  73       |          |
========================
```

2nd key value pair:

```
========================
|  Key      |  Value   |
========================
|  73       |  Feet    |
|  74       |          |
========================
```

Resulting key value pair should be:

```
========================
|  Key      |  Value   |
========================
|  73       |  Foot    |
|           |  Feet    |
========================
```

I have tried:

```
var result = dic.GroupBy(x => x.Key.Intersect(x.Key)).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Select(r => r.Value).ToList());
```

No luck till now.
Here's a snapshot of my dictionary:
[image: Key is only 73 here for Foot and Feet. They may differ as described in example above]

Comment: If your input keys are `[71, 72], [72, 73], [73, 74], [74, 75]`, what do you want your output keys to be?

Comment: [72] for [71,72,[72,73]. 73 for [72,73],[73,74]. 74 for [73,74],[74,75]

Comment: [71,72] for [71,72,73],[71,72,74],[71,72,73,74,75]. just simple intersection.

Comment: Seems like you cannot obtain the key for your new Dictionary, purely based on a single Key-Value pair from your original dictionary. You keep using subsequent Key-Value pair till the intersection yields only one element (or the intersection does not yield zero elements). This means that the order of elements will play a role. Before trying to implement, you need to think through your problem and come up with the exact rules for grouping, and chances are you will have to implement a context based looping solution instead of LINQ

Comment: You're pretty right @Vikhram. Had to do it using context based looping.